# How to SYNC AWS S3 Bucket and local folder using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there any way I can use boto3 to sync up aws s3 bucket and a local folder in windows 10?
I tried reading the documents but didnt find any methods do so

Answer (score 2):

`Boto3` **does not have such functionality**. It is only available in AWS CLI. Which means you would have to implement it yourself, or use [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) to call AWS CLI from a python program,  [sh](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) package or any other way of calling external programs from python.

Comment: Using ```os.system()``` is no longer recommended. Use ```subprocess``` module instead. See, https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements